# Не выводятся данные на страницу в Django

Tags: python, django

Я создаю сайт сокращения ссылок.

И когда надо чтоб все сокращённые ссылки выводились снизу под формой, оно не отображается.

Я читал информацию, но не помогло.

```
#views.py
def links(request):
    form = LinkForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        BASE_URL = request.get_raw_uri()
        if form.is_valid():
            link_urls = Links()
            form.save()
            link_urls.short_url = request.POST.get("short_url")
            form.save()
            link_urls.save()
            return redirect('link-creation')
    return render(request, 'sokratim/links.html', {"form": form, "context_object_name": "urls"})


def redirector(request, key):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Links, key=key)
    return redirect(instance.original_url)
```

```
#models.py
from django.db import models


class Links(models.Model):
    long_url = models.URLField('Длинная ссылка', max_length=255)
    short_url = models.CharField('Сокращённая ссылка', max_length=15, unique=True)


def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.long_url} - {self.short_url}'


class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Link"
    verbose_name_plural = "Links"
```

```
#links.html
{% extends 'sokratim/base.html' %}

{% block title %}
  {{ title }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <form method="post" class="form-links">
    <h2 class="link-short">Сокращение ссылок</h2>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn" style="margin: 0">Сократить</button>
  </form>
  <div class="links">
    {% for urlg in urls %}
      <div class="media-body">
        <h5>Cсылка <a target="_blank" href="{{ urlg.long_url }}">link/{{ urlg.short_url }}/</a></h5>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**Вот сама форма**

[image: Форма сокращения ссылок]

Answer (score 1):

```
from .models import Links


def links(request):
    urls = Links.objects.all()
    form = LinkForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        BASE_URL = request.get_raw_uri()
        if form.is_valid():
            link_urls = Links()
            form.save()
            link_urls.short_url = request.POST.get("short_url")
            form.save()
            link_urls.save()
            return redirect('link-creation')
    return render(request, 'sokratim/links.html', {"form": form, "urls": urls})
```

В словаре `context`(это словарь который вы передаете в `render`) вы должны передавать все ссылки.

1-м вы передаете название переменной, которая будет рендерится в `html` шаблоне.
2-м вы передаете переменную с содержимым, которое вы хотите отправить в `html` шаблон.

Comment: **Спасибо за помощь!**

Comment: У меня другая проблема появляется

https://i.snipboard.io/NFEScm.jpg

При сокращении.

Comment: @ИгроЛайдерIGROLIDER В `short_url` передан параметр `unique=True` это значить, что две записи с одинаковым `short_url` не могут быть.

Comment: У меня теперь ещё одна проблема...((

При нажатии на кнопку сокращения ссылки у меня появляется 2.

https://i.snipboard.io/gmCQZM.jpg

Но одна ссылка ведёт на нужную страницу

https://i.snipboard.io/MBhCfY.jpg

А другая на ту же самую.

https://i.snipboard.io/Hsc6Fp.jpg